# run gdal2tiles.py from python script

Tags: python, gdal

I need help trying to run gdal2tiles.py from a python script. Here is my script:

```
import gdal
from gdalconst import *

fn='test.jpg'
dataset = gdal.Open(fn, GA_ReadOnly )
print 'Size is ',dataset.RasterXSize,'x',dataset.RasterYSize
AvgSize=(dataset.RasterXSize+dataset.RasterYSize)/2
# Works up til this point

gdal2tiles.py -p -z [0-6] test.jpg
```

I keep getting syntax errors and error messages saying "no input file specified".  I'm not very familiar with gdal but all I need is to be able to have this photo tiled.  If someone could show me how to properly do this that would be great.  Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Try adding this to your script:

```
cmd = 'gdal2tiles.py -p -z [0-6] test.jpg'

os.system(cmd)
```

Comment: I have this error:  sh: gdal2tiles.py: command not found
Any idea why?